# Object out of range Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

So I did a very simple loop VBA to consolidate data from different workbook into single workbook. I got the out of range error keep promting me and I've tried my best to think but it's a dead end for me. Appreciate if can get some input from the seniors.

```
Sub consolidate()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set mb = ThisWorkbook

    myfdr = ThisWorkbook.Path
    fname = Dir(myfdr & "\*.csv")

    Do Until fname = Empty
        If fname <> mb.Name Then
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myfdr & "\" & fname)

            mg = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
            Range("M4").Value = mg

            wb.Worksheets.Copy After:=mb.Sheets(mb.Sheets.Count)
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

            n = n + 1
        End If

        fname = Dir
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox n & "Done"
End Sub


Sub Union()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ms = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    fsn = 1
    k = 0

    Set mb = ThisWorkbook
    myfdr = ThisWorkbook.Path
    fname = Dir(myfdr & "\*.csv")

    Do Until fname = Empty
        If fname <> mb.Name Then
            sn = Mid(fname, 1, Len(fname) - 4)
            Set cs = Worksheets(sn) '<<<<The subscript out of range error happened here
            If fsn = 1 Then
                fsn = 0
                For g = 1 To cs.Cells(4, 13)
                    k = k + 1
                    For r = 1 To 10
                        ms.Cells(k, r) = cs.Cells(g, r)
                    Next r
                Next g
            Else
                For g = 9 To cs.Cells(4, 13)
                    k = k + 1
                    For r = 1 To 10
                        ms.Cells(k, r) = cs.Cells(g, r)
                    Next r
                Next g
            End If
        End If

        fname = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: First, it is recommended to use `Option Explicit` at the start of the modules and to declare your variables, it will greatly speed up debugging process.

Comment: And you should format (indent) your code nicely. That would also help you/us to speed up debugging process (I did that in your question).

Comment: Next, check the value of `sn`, when the error occurs. There is probably no worksheet on the workbook with that index. How to process this depends on your intentions